# Rails not auto loading engine code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have some rails apps and rails engines, their structure is like this:

```
rails_app_1/
rails_app_2/
etc......
rails_engine_x/
rails_engine_y/
rails_engine_z/
rails_engine_w/
```

Each rails_app loads a subset of these engines, so for example rails_app1_1 Gemfile may have this code

```
gem 'rails_engine_x','0.0.1', path: '../rails_engine_x'
gem 'rails_engine_y','0.0.1', path: '../rails_engine_y'
```

Now the problem is that on development mode, when changing some code, it seems that code auto loading is broken and I get strange errors that are fixed when I close the server and open it again. For example I may get some errors like (`Constant Foo is not defined`-where it is actually defined-), and other times I got some error`(undefined method serialize_from_session for #<Class:0x00000009762628>)` which is a method from devise defined on User class which was working normally, only when changing the code in development mode while the server is running then it is not defined. So I need to restart the server to get the code reloaded correctly. Any help on this? I read about rails auto loading but couldn't find a clue.

Comment: Are you sure auto loading works for gems, even if they're local?

Comment: @Oleander no I'm not sure :) but even if code is not reloaded, why the app is broken and I need to restart the server after each change, so a change is not just not loaded, but also break the app!

Comment: @Oleander I checked another app that has some local Gem(Engine), and yes changed code in Gem is reloaded automatically, so I don't know what is wrong with these particular apps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is solved, it was because of a strange initializing code that was trying to include some modules manually, when I changed it, every thing worked.